# Using gatsbyjs with redux-saga

Tags: redux-saga, gatsby

I am trying to add redux-saga with gatsby but I get an error on console.

```
regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at Object../src/reduxifier/actions/blog.js (blog.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 419ed32a0dab354fc31d:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 419ed32a0dab354fc31d:86)
    at Object../src/reduxifier/saga.js (saga.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 419ed32a0dab354fc31d:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 419ed32a0dab354fc31d:86)
    at Object../src/reduxifier/store.js (store.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 419ed32a0dab354fc31d:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 419ed32a0dab354fc31d:86)
    at Object../gatsby/configureRedux.js (configureRedux.js:9)
```

src/reduxifier/actions/blog.js

```
import {put} from "redux-saga/effects";

function* fetchBlog(action) {
    try {
        // const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId);
        yield put({type: "BLOG_FETCH_SUCCESS", user: {"const" : 1}});
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({type: "BLOG_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
    }
}

export {fetchBlog};
```

I have have added `"babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0"` in my dev-dependencies and in babelrc file.

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": [
    ["add-module-exports", "transform-runtime", "transform-regenerator"]
  ]
}
```

Can you help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing `regenerator-runtime` as well?